# cups remove jobs after 5 minutes

Tags: cups, ghostscript

I have a print job that uses ghostscript as a filter to print a composite ps file. This file produces errors to the `/var/log/cups/error_log` and is not being removed from the queue even after 1 day (from the cupsd.conf)

Until I debug the ps error, is there a configuration option to remove those print jobs from cups? I know you can use `cancel -a` but this is integral to a system that cannot be accessed thru ssh constantly.

I tried using the setting of `MaxJobTime 300` and `PreserveJobFiles 300` to `/etc/cups/cupsd.conf` but I don't see anything working properly.

I am using `9.26~dfsg+0-0ubuntu0.16.04.11` ghostscript version and `2.1.3-4ubuntu0.10` cups.